# sorl thumbnail with cloudinary remote storage

Tags: python, django, cloudinary, sorl-thumbnail

Can't seem to find any info regarding using sorl.thumbnail with cloudinary.

I managed to make it kinda work, but it generates thumbs on each reload which is obviously not right. For the information, I use cloudinary for media files only.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.